# Identifying rows with multiple IDs linked to a unique value

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Using ms-sql 2008 r2; am sure this is very straightforward. I am trying to identify where a unique value {ISIN} has been linked to more than 1 Identifier. An example output would be:

```
isin            entity_id
XS0276697439    000BYT-E
XS0276697439    000BYV-E
```

This is actually an error and I want to look for other instances where there may be more than one entity_id linked to a unique ISIN.

This is my current working but it's obviously not correct:

```
select isin, entity_id from edm_security_entity_map
where isin is not null
--and isin = ('XS0276697439')
group by isin, entity_id
having COUNT(entity_id) > 1
order by isin asc
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Elliot,

I don't have a copy of SQL in front of me right now, so apologies if my syntax isn't spot on.

I'd start by finding the duplicates:

```
select
   x.isin
  ,count(*)
from edm_security_entity_map as x
group by x.isin
having count(*) > 1
```

Then join that back to the full table to find where those duplicates come from:

```
;with DuplicateList as
(
select
   x.isin
  --,count(*)     -- not used elsewhere
from edm_security_entity_map as x
group by x.isin
having count(*) > 1
)
select
   map.isin
  ,map.entity_id
from edm_security_entity_map as map
inner join DuplicateList as dup
  on dup.isin = map.isin;
```

HTH,
Michael

So you're saying that if isin-1 has a row for both entity-1 and entity-2 that's an error but isin-3, say, linked to entity-3 in two separe rows is OK?  The ugly-but-readable solution to that is to pre-pend another CTE on the previous solution

```
;with UniqueValues as
(select distinct
   y.isin
  ,y.entity_id
from  edm_security_entity_map as y
)
,DuplicateList as
(
select
   x.isin
  --,count(*)     -- not used elsewhere
from UniqueValues as x
group by x.isin
having count(*) > 1
)
select
   map.isin
  ,map.entity_id
from edm_security_entity_map as map  -- or from UniqueValues, depening on your objective.
inner join DuplicateList as dup
  on dup.isin = map.isin;
```

There are better solutions with additional GROUP BY clauses in the final query.  If this is going into production I'd be recommending that.  Or if your table has a bajillion rows.  If you just need to do some analysis the above should suffice, I hope.

Comment: Thanks Michael; almost there. That also returns where multiple entity ID's that are the same are linked to the ISIN, which is ok. It's where the entity ID is different I want to isolate the occurence. I made a slight edit to the code above.